# Ola pessoal, tenho um trabalho pra fazer da facul sobre python e to com certa dificuldade

Tags: python, algoritmo

Implementar um programa que fornecidos o nome e a idade de um criança classifique-a em uma das seguintes etapas de ensino:
Ensino                      Faixa etária
Educaçao Infantil           1 a 5
Ensino Fundamental I        6 a 10
Ensino Fundamental          11 a 14
Ensino médio                 maiores de 15 anos
O usuário deve ainda ter a opção de escolher se quer encerrar o programa ou não. e a saida deve ficar assim
nome da criança: tal
idade: 04
A aluna tal tem tal idade e esta no ensino infantil
deseja continuar? 0 - nao   1 - sim

MEU CODIGO FICOU ASSIM:

```
aluno = dict()  
aluno ['nome:'] = str(input('nome: '))  
aluno ['idade:'] = float(input(f'idade de {aluno["nome:"]}: '))  
if aluno['idade:'] <= 5:  
    aluno['ensino:'] = 'infantil'  
elif 1 >= aluno['idade:'] <=5:     
    aluno ['ensino:'] = 'infantil '     
if aluno['idade:'] <= 10:     
        aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino fundamental I'   
elif 6 >= aluno['idade:'] <= 10:
    aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino fundamental I'
if aluno['idade:'] <= 14:
        aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino fundamental II'
elif 11 >= aluno['idade:'] <= 14:
        aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino fundamental II'
if aluno['idade:'] >= 15:
            aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino medio'  
for k,v in aluno.items():
    print(f'{k}  {v}')
```

O problema é que qualquer idade abaixo de 14 que eu coloco so sai ensino  fundamental II, nao sai as outras opcoes de acordo com a idade da criança

Answer (score -2):

Não sei a sintaxe da linguagem Python, mas já resolvi problemas semelhantes com outras linguagens. A sua estrutura condicional deveria ser aninhada, por exemplo:

```
aluno = dict()  
aluno ['nome:'] = str(input('nome: '))  
aluno ['idade:'] = float(input(f'idade de {aluno["nome:"]}: '))  
if 1>= aluno['idade:'] <= 5:  
    aluno['ensino:'] = 'infantil'    
elif aluno['idade:'] <= 10:     
    aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino fundamental I'   
elif aluno['idade:'] <= 14:
    aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino fundamental II'
else
    aluno['ensino:'] = 'ensino medio'  
for k,v in aluno.items():
    print(f'{k}  {v}')
```

Repito: não sei a sintaxe do Python.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
while True:
    aluno = dict()
    aluno['nome'] = str(input('Digite o nome do aluno: '))  
    aluno['idade'] = int(input(f'Digite a idade de {aluno["nome"]}: '))

    if aluno['idade'] <= 5:
        aluno['ensino'] = 'Ensino Infantil'
    elif aluno['idade'] >= 6 and aluno['idade'] <= 13:
        aluno['ensino'] = 'Ensino Fundamental I'
    elif aluno['idade'] > 13 and aluno['idade'] <= 14:
        aluno['ensino'] = 'Ensino Fundamental II'
    elif aluno['idade'] >= 15:
        aluno['ensino'] = 'Ensino Médio'
    for k, v in aluno.items():
        print(f'{k}: {v}')

    print('\nDeseja continuar?\n[0] Não\n[1] Sim')
    option = int(input('R: '))

    if option == 0:
        break
```

**lembre-se de indentar o código. caso contrário, não vai funcionar...**

eu tinha colado o código errado aqui, corrigi.

ta assim:

[image: foto mostrando o codigo funcionando]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).